# Eclipse to svn repository connection problem

Tags: subversive

my  eclipse can connect to svn repository yesterday. but this morning when i try to connect to svn repository it cant. it shows authentication page again and again although user name and password is correct. 
what can be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your password was changed or expired?
Try to check the SVN-log.

Comment: i ve checked the password from server it is true